# How to update UI when a property change

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, properties

I'm trying to update my UI when a property in my BL class changes. Please can someone advise the best way to do this in vb.net

Comment: please show an example of what is or is not happening and describe what this things is: custom control? user control? inherited control? std control?

Comment: I am running a sql backup and using the SqlInfoMessage to get percentage complete print messages. At this point I update a public property in my class that I would like the value of a text box in my UI to be. However, I'm not sure how to update my UI as soon as the property changes rather than jumping from an empty text box to the full output of the backup print messages.

Comment: if `myTextBox.Text = someTextToShow` doesnt work then you should share the code; if it is in some loop Windows wont perform each update and is rather what a progress bar is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a really precise question so I will explain the standard way (in my opinion).

Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your class and handle the `PropertyChanged` event of your object.

First the the class of the object that contains the property in question:

```
Public Class MySweetClass
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _MyProperty As String
    Public Property MyProperty As String
        Get
            Return _MyProperty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _MyProperty = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

Notice that the `PropertyChanged` event is raised once the value of the property changes.

In your form handle this event:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents MySweetObject As MySweetClass

    Private Sub MySweetObject_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles MySweetObject.PropertyChanged
        'Update gui here
    End Sub
End Class
```

This lets you update the GUI whenever the value changes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will provide more information in the future but that works a treat!